# Angular JS - How to find string in array with objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and have a limited background in JavaScript, so sorry if I am not explaining this right.

I am looking to show an image based upon a value in an array that contains objects. Here is what I have, which works:

```
<img ng-show="user.Groups[0].Name=='Consumers'" src="images/home.jpg" />
```

The problem that I am running into is that [0] could also be [1], [2], [3], etc. What can I use to ensure it checks all indexes?

Comment: Create a function that iterates and checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.

Put this in your controller:

```
$scope.objArrayContains = function(arr, keyName, val) {
    return arr.map(function(a) { return a[keyName]; }).indexOf(val) !== -1;
};
```

Then your HTML can be like this:

```
<img ng-show="objArrayContains(user.Groups, 'Name', 'Consumers')" src="images/home.jpg" />
```